# Grep return wrong result

Tags: linux, grep

I need search lines without term `\t42\t`.

I use:

```
grep -w -v '\t42\t' file.txt > tmp.txt
```

Why have I line with term `\t42\t` in result file?

Comment: try grep -E i.e. extended grep and \\t42\\t escape characters for ignoring meta characters

Comment: wait, do you want to match literal `\t42\t` or `<tab>42<tab>`??

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this result because for `grep` the `\t` sequence means "one tab character". You must escape the backslash characters for them to be treated litteraly:

```
grep -w -v '\\t42\\t' file.txt > tmp.txt
```

Comment: Interpreting `\t` as tab is an extension. Traditionally, it would simply match a literal `t` (i.e. backslashes would basically be ignored in front of non-metacharacters). Either way, the expression does not match the literal string `\t`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could fix this by using `grep -F`, which disables all metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `-w` as it doesn't work if you append non-word characters to the pattern:

```
grep -v '\t42\t' file.txt > tmp.txt
```